# How to check if encrypted Zip archive in PHP?

Tags: php, encryption, zip, php-ziparchive

As I understand it, the status is archive encrypted contains in general purpose bit flag. I try to check this with ZipArchive::statname(), but it seems that can not get the information by this method.

What else I can do? Read the archive and parse the headers? I know that I can call system(), but I do not want to use this method because of its specificity (some hosting this function is disabled).

Comment: What have you tried with ZipArchive::statname? Do you get an error message? Please give us some more information.

Comment: ZipArchive open encrypted files, but provides not enough information. An [example](http://pastebin.com/ZetmVLKa) of the return value of the method `ZipArchive::statIndex()`. I tried to identify encrypted archive by `comp_method`, but found no dependency.

Comment: Ticksy i even made simple function for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the ZIP standard: http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT.

From section 4.3.7:

```
4.3.7  Local file header:

  local file header signature     4 bytes  (0x04034b50)
  version needed to extract       2 bytes
  general purpose bit flag        2 bytes
  compression method              2 bytes
  ...
```

From section 4.4.4:

```
4.4.4 general purpose bit flag: (2 bytes)

    Bit 0: If set, indicates that the file is encrypted.
    ...
```

So you need to check FIRST BIT of the seventh byte and not the whole byte. You must do the checking for each file, as each file can be encrypted individually (section 4.3.6).

Answer (score 5):

ZIP file header: (encrypted file vs normal file)

[image]

`09` seemts to be the encryption flag.

Check 7th byte is `0x09`

```
function zip_is_encrypted($filename) {
  $handle = fopen($filename, "rb");
  $contents = fread($handle, 7);
  fclose($handle);
  return $contents[6] == 0x09;
}
```

Comment: +1 a reference to some official document specifying the bits would be nice

Comment: @owlstead [standard](http://www.pkware.com/documents/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT). About encryption: 
`4.4.4 general purpose bit flag: (2 bytes)
  Bit 0: If set, indicates that the file is encrypted.`

Comment: @owlstead You need to check FIRST BIT of seventh byte.

Comment: Peter answer does not work.
Different zip apps place differente info at the top of the file. For instance, Izarc 4.3 zip file with password will have a 03 value on 7th byte and a 02 if is not protected with password.

Answer (score 0):

That's not working, because the Header can repeat n-times.

To workaround this, open the zip zip_open() and try to read every entry zip_entry_open()

If there is an unreadable entry, the zip could be encrypted!